# How to transmit audio wirlessly from a non bluetooth device to a bluetooth phone?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I want to transmit audio from a device having an earphone jack to an android phone wirelessly. How to accomplish it over Bluetooth.

I looked at ED05 Bluetooth board and A2DP, H2DP profiles but could only make out that audio can be transmitted from a phone to these devices.

Comment: Google "phone jack bluetooth transmitter" is returning around 1M results.

Comment: The hardware for this is easy - probably any of the 1M results which Eugene googled would work. Your problem is getting android to receive audio over bluetooth, so this question would probably be better suited to the android SE.